# What is the way to serialize data as C# code?

Tags: c#, serialization

Let's say I would like to serialize `points` as JSON:

```
  var points = new List<Point>();
  points.Add(GetPoint());
```

I would probably get something like this:

```
[
  { "x" : 4, "y" : 3 }
]
```

but now I would like to serialize the data as C# code, so I would get:

```
  var data = new List<Point>();
  data.Add(new Point(4,3));
```

The serialization should produce valid C# code, so except for root variable name potential conflict, would be ready to copy&paste into actual program.

How to achieve this?

*Maybe Expression trees would be useful, I know next to nothing about it, but I will check it out. I am afraid of complexity and I am not sure how it will handle refactoring, see below.*

**Background**: this is for making almost automatic tests, in case of a problem I would dump data as C# code, copy&paste it as unit test, and because it would be C# code, it could be polished, refactored, etc. For example if I ever would like to change property name from "x" to "X" there would be zero problems with it.

Comment: This article seems of interest: [Try the new System.Text.Json source generator](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-the-new-system-text-json-source-generator/)

Comment: you could dump the data as json and just deserialise it in your test

Comment: @FranzGleichmann, Any data stored on disk are out of scope when it comes to refactoring the code. See the remark at the end of my question.

Comment: @greenoldman i meant you could embed the JSON as string in your code snippet.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann, what tool parses strings to C# code on the fly and treat the content as C# code, so when you refactor your types, then this tool knows all the bindings, and refactor strings accordingly?